# How to deserialize a JSON array with no name, using RestAssured?

Tags: arrays, json, jackson, deserialization, rest-assured

Hy, I ran into a bit of an issue when trying to deserialize an API Response using RestAssured. The response I get back from the server is in the form of an array - an array of Genre objects - but the array has no name:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5ff71f94a76e49001374c84a",
        "name": "world",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

I have an API that returns a single genre object.

I created a class for deserializing the single Genre object.

```
// class used for deserializing Genre object response

public class Genre {

    public String _id;
    public String name;
    public int __v;
}
```

and this class for deserializing the response with the array

```
// class used for deserializing Genres array response

public class Genres {

    public List<Genre> genres;
}
```

RestAssured is expecting me to deserialize the response in the following format:

```
GenresResponse genresResponse = response.getBody().as(GenresResponse.class);
genreId = genresResponse.genres.get(0)._id;
```

Due to the fact that the array response does not have any name properties, the Array deserialization will fail with the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `apiEngine.models.responses.GenresResponse` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (String)"[{"_id":"5ff72762a76e49001374c853","name":"SciFi","__v":0}]"; line: 1, column: 1]
```

I am using the following dependency for serialization and deserialization:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there any way I can deserialize the response which contains the Array of Genres?

Comment: You showed us `Genres` class but in the code you use `GenresResponse`. Why the mismatch?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need class containing List because you can use array in Object Mapper like this:

```
Genre[] genres = response.jsonPath().getObject("$", Genre[].class);
```

Where $ is the beginning of the JSON.

You can also transform it to List<> instead of array like this:

```
List<Genre> genres = Arrays.asList(response.jsonPath().getObject("$", Genre[].class));
```